# Copy Audio directly to audio buffer on iPhone

Tags: iphone, audio

Is there a way to copy to an AudioQueueBuffer directly?

I am looking to re-create an Android app that used android.AudioTrack's  write() function to write directly to a sound buffer.  Can I do a similar thing using the AudioQueueBuffer on the iPhone?

I was going to do something along the lines of:

```
AudioQueueAllocateBuffer( mAudioQueueData.mQueue, dataSize, &mAudioQueueData.mBuffer);
mAudioQueueData.mBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = dataSize;
memcpy(mAudioQueueData.mBuffer->mAudioData, soundData, dataSize);
AudioQueueStart(mAudioQueueData.mQueue, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, what your looking for is called RemoteIO. It's kinda hard to set up first, but gives you direct control of the audio buffer and is the lowest-level audio API on the iPhone.

Check out this tutorial to get started: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

There are also these useful series of blog posts: http://timbolstad.com/2010/03/14/core-audio-getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

The audio buffers are only designed to be written to (meaningfully) inside an audio queue callback.  But you can always copy/queue sound data to your own intermediate buffer, and then copy that data again from the intermediate buffer to the audio queue buffers during the audio queue callbacks.  It's one additional step that isn't rocket science.

Audio Unit RemoteIO buffers work in a similar manner.

Comment: I was looking at Apples example and I setup an AudioQueueCallback.  What I wasn't sure of was the "right" way to copy into the AudioQueueBuffer.  If I just move the memcpy into the AudioQueueCallback then Enqueue the buffer should all be good?

Comment: You can use memcpy if the data matches the audio queue data format in sample format, size, packing, endianess, and etc.